# SVG - moving a dot along a fixed circle following the mouse position

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to animate a point to follow the potion of the mouse.

It's like an eye looking at the arrow while I'm not on the eye.
The point should move along a circle if I mouve around the mouse.
If the mouse is on the eye, the eye should follow the arrow.

That's what I'm currently trying to do.
I use snap.svg library.

I currently have a point following the mobility of the mouse but I cant make it stay in a circle.

It looks like this so far :

```
var s = Snap(400,400);
var c1 = s.circle(0,0,10).attr({ fill: "red" });

function OnMouseMove(evt) {
    c1.attr({ cx: evt.clientX , cy: evt.clientY });
}
document.onmousemove = OnMouseMove;
```

Any idea community ?

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my visual solution, it uses Snap's built in functions:-

```
var s = Snap(400,400);
var circleX = 150, circleY = 150, circleRadius = 100;
var bigCircle = s.circle(circleX, circleY, circleRadius);
var L1 = s.path("M "+circleX+" "+circleY +"L 0 0").attr({stroke: "blue"});
// BigCircle default its black, lets change its attributes
bigCircle.attr({
    fill: "#bada55",
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 5
});
var c1 = s.circle(0,0,10).attr({ fill: "red" });

function OnMouseMove(evt) {
    L1.attr({ d: "M "+circleX+" "+circleY +"L "+evt.clientX+" "+evt.clientY });
    var totalLength = L1.getTotalLength();
    if (totalLength < circleRadius) {
        c1.attr({ cx: evt.clientX , cy: evt.clientY });
    } else {
        var PAL = L1.getPointAtLength(circleRadius);
        c1.attr({ cx: PAL.x , cy: PAL.y });
    }
}
document.onmousemove = OnMouseMove;
```

Update: Here's the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/JwkYm/7/). Challenge for readers: Try `var bigCircle = s.ellipse(150, 150, 100, 50);`.

Comment: Very smart solution. It works great and does exactly what I expected ! Thanks !!

Comment: For the reader challenge, I've extended your answer below, hope you don't mind! http://jsfiddle.net/JwkYm/8/

Answer (score 3):

You have to test how far away your mouse coordinates are from the centre of the circle, and stop them if they reach the edge.

Something like this should work.

```
function OnMouseMove(evt) {
    // Get the mouse position relative to the centre of the circle (circleX,circleY)
    var  dx = evt.clientX - circleX;
    var  dy = evt.clientY - circleY;
    // Calculate distance from centre of circle to mouse (Pythagoras' theorem)
    var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy *dy);
    // Test against radius
    if (distance > circleRadius) {
       // Scale the dx,dy coords back so they are on the circumference
       dx = dx * circleRadius / distance;
       dy = dy * circleRadius / distance;
    }
    c1.attr({ cx: dx, cy: dy });
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, make a jsfiddle so we can see what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

Just strayling slightly, but as an extension to Alvin Ks answer (for the readers challenge!), if you can make sure the the object is a path, you could use Snap.path.intersection which would work for many other shapes. It would need an extra bit of code for multiple intersections though possibly.

Relevant amendment to Alvins code...

```
function OnMouseMove(evt) {
    L1.attr({ d: "M "+circleX+" "+circleY +"L "+evt.clientX+" "+evt.clientY });
    var intersect = Snap.path.intersection( path, L1 )
    if (intersect.length == 0) {
        c1.attr({ cx: evt.clientX , cy: evt.clientY });
    } else {
        c1.attr({ cx: intersect[0].x , cy: intersect[0].y });
    } 
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JwkYm/8/)

Comment: +1 @Ian: Good job. For `.ellipse()`, [convert it to path](http://complexdan.com/svg-circleellipse-to-path-converter/) and the the rest of the coding is identical. Reminds me of `xeyes` from the early days.