# SVG drag elements on the edges of the path

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have the path as described in the attached image 1, and I want to drag and drop the another element (as rounded red) on the edges of the drawn path, so at the end I want to drag the red marked element on the black line that is edge of the path, not inside the path,and now i can move inside and outside the path, but I want only to be on the border of the path

So here I have the customized the code as below on the `mouseMove` function and on the `select` case svgedit.compiled.js

```
if (path_child == 'path') {
    var line_rotate = 90;
    if (group_w_d == "drag_drop_D") {
        var test = 'rotate(' + line_rotate + ',' + line_pt.x + ',' + line_pt.y + ') translate(' + trans_x + ',' + line_pt.y + ') scale(' + width + ',' + height + ')';
    } else {
        var test = 'rotate(' + line_rotate + ',' + line_pt.x + ',' + line_pt.y + ') translate(' + line_pt.x + ',' + line_pt.y + ') scale(' + width + ',' + height + ')';
    }
    selectedElements[0].setAttribute('transform', test);

    var cls = selectedElements[0].getAttribute('class');
    //alert(cls);
    $('.' + cls).each(function() {
        $(this).attr('transform', test)
    });
}
```

[image: Image one]
[image: Image two]

For example here is the fiddle link [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzic/kKLtH/), which I want exactly, here we can move the ellipse on the path wherever we want, but I want it to be on the edges of my path elements

**Edited:**
For example just imagine that we are creating a room using rectangle and in this room we have to fix a door or window,like marked as rounded red, so we can move the path along all the position of the rectangle but it should only on the edges not inside the `rect` or outside the `rect`, there is no problem about it we done it,

But now we want split the wall to extended wall so we converted the `rect` into `path` after converting this the doors or windows are not moving along with the edges of the `path` instead of this the doors are moving anywhere on the working area of the `SVG-EDIT`

and here my doors and windows are the `g` not `ellipse`, so i know ellipse only have the cx,cy and `g` may have the `transform` so am not clear how to do it
i hope this will make sense

Comment: Since the [linked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzic/kKLtH/) does what you want (the shape moves only along the edges of the path), can you explain how you are having a difficulty adapting that to your situation?

Comment: in the fiddle attached they used `Raphael.js` and am using `SVG` alone so i don't know how to adapt this function to my `SVG-Edit`

Comment: Can you rewrite the question to more clearly explain that?  There is nothing Raphael-specific about the `getTotalLength` and `getPointAtLength` methods: they are both [defined in the SVG specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathElement).  Everything else is easy to translate to standard Javascript, once you've actually drawn the relevant shapes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429067/svg-moving-a-dot-along-a-fixed-circle-following-the-mouse-position/25440720#25440720), see the comment section for triangle fiddle (*SO wont let me post fiddle link w/o code*). Basically extend line from the centroid of triangle and calculate the intersection path.

Edit: In native SVG, you need an [intersection](http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/index.htm) library for line with line

Do post the updated code here for future readers.